# How to cancel download Docker installer?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

When I click "install" button, vscode docker extension begins to download the Docker installer.

[image]

How to cancel it? There is no "cancel" button.

[image]

Comment: I think you simply can disconnect your internet connection or close VSCode. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Start vscode in Safe mode from Terminal or CMD with the command `code -r .`, then
[uninstall](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_uninstall-an-extension)
the Docker extension.

If this is still happening, try it again without internet.

[image]